# Spanish word tokeniser

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I would like to tokenise Spanish sentences into words. Is the following the correct approach or is there a better way of doing this?

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def spanish_word_tokenize(s):
    for w in word_tokenize(s):    
        if w[0] in ("¿","¡"):   
            yield w[0]
            yield w[1:]
        else:
            yield w          

sentences = "¿Quién eres tú? ¡Hola! ¿Dónde estoy?"

spanish_sentence_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/spanish.pickle')

sentences = spanish_sentence_tokenizer.tokenize(sentences)
for s in sentences:
    print([s for s in spanish_word_tokenize(s)])
```

Comment: looks good to me, but that you need to do this looks more like a error in the nltk part, maybe you should report it to them

Comment: Please avoid cross posting between SO and github regarding your questions, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C.f. NLTK github issue [#1214](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1214), there are quite a few alternative tokenizers in NLTK =)

E.g. using NLTK port of @jonsafari [toktok tokenizer](https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok):

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('perluniprops')
[nltk_data] Downloading package perluniprops to
[nltk_data]     /Users/liling.tan/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package perluniprops is already up-to-date!
True
>>> nltk.download('nonbreaking_prefixes')
[nltk_data] Downloading package nonbreaking_prefixes to
[nltk_data]     /Users/liling.tan/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package nonbreaking_prefixes is already up-to-date!
True
>>> from nltk.tokenize.toktok import ToktokTokenizer
>>> toktok = ToktokTokenizer()
>>> sent = u"¿Quién eres tú? ¡Hola! ¿Dónde estoy?"
>>> toktok.tokenize(sent)
[u'\xbf', u'Qui\xe9n', u'eres', u't\xfa', u'?', u'\xa1Hola', u'!', u'\xbf', u'D\xf3nde', u'estoy', u'?']
>>> print " ".join(toktok.tokenize(sent))
¿ Quién eres tú ? ¡Hola ! ¿ Dónde estoy ?

>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize
>>> sentences = u"¿Quién eres tú? ¡Hola! ¿Dónde estoy?"
>>> [toktok.tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(sentences, language='spanish')]
[[u'\xbf', u'Qui\xe9n', u'eres', u't\xfa', u'?'], [u'\xa1Hola', u'!'], [u'\xbf', u'D\xf3nde', u'estoy', u'?']]

>>> print '\n'.join([' '.join(toktok.tokenize(sent)) for sent in sent_tokenize(sentences, language='spanish')])
¿ Quién eres tú ?
¡Hola !
¿ Dónde estoy ?
```

If you hack the code a little and add `u'\xa1'` in https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/toktok.py#L51 , you should be able to get:

```
[[u'\xbf', u'Qui\xe9n', u'eres', u't\xfa', u'?'], [u'\xa1', u'Hola', u'!'], [u'\xbf', u'D\xf3nde', u'estoy', u'?']]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler solution by using spacy. However, only works previous download of spacy data: **python -m spacy download es**

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('es')
sentences = "¿Quién eres tú? ¡Hola! ¿Dónde estoy?"
doc = nlp(sentences)
tokens = [token for token in doc]
print(tokens)
```

Gives a correct answer:

```
[¿, Quién, eres, tú, ?, ¡, Hola, !, ¿, Dónde, estoy, ?]
```

I don't recommend nltk ToktokTokenizer since according to the documentation "*the input must be one sentence per line; thus only final period is tokenized.*" so you have to worry about segment by sentences first.